# Forward ZC bond with Hull-White model

Tags: calibration, hullwhite

I am interested in finding the price of a forward zero coupon bond B(t0,t1,t2) under the Hull-White model. To arrive at this result, it makes sense to proceed in this way:

1. calculate `P(t,T) = A(t,T)*exp{-B(t,T )r(t)}`with the Hull-White model
2. calibrate the parameters a,sigma of the model through the cap/floor
3. I see `B(t0,t1,t2)= P(t0,t2)/P(t0,t1)

In case it is wrong I would appreciate an explanation of the error and a solution to get to B(t0,t1,t2) with the Hull-White model. Thank you

`